# Is there any information about the Boeing 787 L/N 6 (ex-Mexican Air Force One)?

Tags: boeing-787, head-of-state-transport, mexico

That Boeing 787 ([L/N 6](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/boeing-787-xc-mex-fuerza-aerea-mexicana-mexican-air-force/roxoo0); N787ZA then  XC-MEX) is (was) the Mexican Air Force One, and recently there has been some turmoil about if this is was acquired under lease or if it was a full purchase.

I was roaming around but I did not find any info about the bidding process.

Is there any info about it?

This plane is supposed to be in auction, but I doubt it can if its leased, in any case it can be transferred, but since its a VIP transport I highly doubt any airline or operator would be interested in it.

By the way it is in storage in San Bernardino, California.

Comment: Related: [Can the Mexican presidential aircraft be sold?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53540/14897)